# Java NavigableMap why is headMap return different for same methods

Tags: java, treemap

Regarding Java TreeMap method (or NavigableMap interface):

```
public SortedMap<K,V> headMap(K toKey)
public NavigableMap<K,V> headMap(K toKey, boolean inclusive)
```

Why do they return different types? I know SortedMap is super to NavigableMap, I just want to know why an inclusive flag requires a different return.

Looking at the code makes no sense either as the version without the inclusive flag simply calls the other.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the reason is historic. [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) itself and [`headMap(K)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#headMap%28K%29) date back to Java 1.2, whereas [`NavigableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) and [`headMap(K, boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#headMap%28K,%20boolean%29) have been introduced in Java 1.6.

Comment: oh, thanks. It was just a bit confusing, especially when my code decided not to work :) you'd think they'd keep it the same though.